# 3d pdf from qgis, version 3.0 and above

Tags: qgis, 3d, pdf

Is it possible to create a 3D pdf from qgis 3d mapview (version 3 "Girona" and above)?

I have tried with Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro Extended (3D capture) and it does not work. 
The adobe works fine with other apps/programs that I use but with qgis I get an error message: "An error occured during 3D capture. Capture settings for this application may be unadapted."